# Specifying the projectname within the DesktopPackageLocation during the Visual Studio Build task in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Folks,

I'm using the Visual Studio Build task in TFS 2018 to build multiple .NET Core 2.0 web applications.

The solution parameter is:
**\WebApp.*.sln

Where each solution is something like WebApp.Prj1.sln, WebApp.Prj2.sln, etc.

The MSBuild arguments are:
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip"

What I would like is to create the webapp.zip file specific to the solution I'm building.  In other words, something like:
/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\$(build.projectname).zip"

I don't seem to be able to find a built-in variable that allows me to access the solution or project name getting built.

Is this possible?  If not, can someone post the equivalent powershell script that emulates the Visual Studio Build task so I can manually create the zipfile with the project name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by default and there is no built-in variable either.

If you want to customize the PowerShell script of Visual Studio build task. You could find the `VSBuild.ps1` script under the build agent working directory _work/vstsbuildxxtask folder on your build agent machine.

Take a look at this thread: [Visual Studio Build step should allow multiple paths](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1643)

Another way is using multiple Visual Studio Build tasks combined with [Copy and Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts?view=vsts) to handle multiple `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\$(build.projectname).zip` packages per project.

---

**Update:**

There already been a related uservoice entry here： [*Using Variable in Solution Path in a Visual Studio Build Task*](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16754890-using-variable-in-solution-path-in-a-visual-studio)

For your request, as a workaround, you could apply the whole solution path as a build variable and change it at build time. That means define a variable and set the value "$/repository/Development/Prj1/website name.sln". If you want build Prj2, change the Prj1 to Prj2 when queuing the build.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  Can you point me in the right direction for getting the solution name to the build task? Within the vsbuild.ps1 script, I see the following input parameter:
    [string]$solution = Get-VstsInput -Name Solution -Require
I gather that this brings the current solution into this script.  From there, I see the line where the $MSBuildArgs are formatted:
    $MSBuildArgs = Format-MSBuildArguments -MSBuildArguments $MSBuildArgs -Platform $Platform ...etc.

Would I simply add an additional parameter here?  Such as:
-SolutionName $solution

Thanks again

Comment: @ArjayH. Sorry for the later reply, didn't  be notified of your comment in SO.  After double check this, there is no such kind of variable, it is not supported in the Visual Studio Build step.  And already has  a related user voice [Using Variable in Solution Path in a Visual Studio Build Task](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16754890-using-variable-in-solution-path-in-a-visual-studio), you could vote up and follow it, TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: @ArjayH. For your request,  I come up with a workaround, you could **apply the whole solution path as a build variables** and **change it at build time**. That mean define a variable and set the value "$/repository/Development/Prj1/website name.sln ". If you want build Prj2, change the Prj1 to Prj2 when queue build.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Your earlier suggestion got me looking into VSBuild.ps1 script which led me to understand how it works.  I found that the solution parameters and build parameters are passed to the VSBuild.ps1 script just once.  For what I was needing, I was hoping that parameters such as build.SolutionName or build.ProjectName would be changed based on the solution getting built at the time.  Instead this whole thing is fixed up and pass directly to msbuild.

Comment: What would be cool is a loop task that wraps the Visual Studio Build Task that sets solution/project variables based on the current sln/project.  This loop task would take a solution parameter of something like '**\WebApp.*.sln', loop through it and get the first sln/csproj of WebApp.prj1.sln and WebApp.prj1.csproj, set this as build.SolutionName, build.ProjectName parameters and call the VS Build task and repeat for other sln/proj's matching the pattern. I ended up solving my immediate problem by referencing a custom profile within the project that did the packaging.

Comment: Patrick, I've filed a user voice ticket at: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34352401-create-a-visual-studio-build-iterator-task.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple Visual Studio Build tasks, one for each solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this won't work because there is going to be new WebApp.PrjN.sln solutions added constantly and I don't want to have to manually add a build task every time one gets added.